# Upgrading to create-react-app version 4.0 with react-app-rewired: server start error

Tags: reactjs, decorator, create-react-app, mobx, react-app-rewired

I've been searching the Web and can't find this situation mentioned anywhere, although it must be not uncommon.

I've been using `create-react-app` (version 3.4.x) with `react-app-rewired` [primarily in order to enable decorator support (for MobX) without ejecting].

I recently tried to upgrade `cra` to the latest version (4.0), following the instructions, by running this command:

```
yarn add --exact react-scripts@4.0.0
```

However, now when starting my React server, I get this error:

```
yarn start
yarn run v1.22.5
$ HTTPS=true BROWSER=none react-app-rewired start --env=local
Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

If I remove `react-app-rewired` and change the start script back to using `react-scripts`, the server starts but I don't have decorator support anymore.

Questions: Does `react-app-rewired` support `cra` 4.0? Is there an alternative solution for enabling decorators without ejecting? Thanks for any input!

Comment: Hi @mjh ! Did you find a solution to the server start error?

Comment: Any other update on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Don't have an answer for `rewired` stuff, but in MobX 6 there is new thing that will probably allow you to drop decorators altogether, `makeAutoObservable`:

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx"

class Store {
  // Don't need decorators now
  string = 'Test String';

  setString = (string) => {
    this.string = string;
  };

  constructor() {
    // Just call it here
    makeAutoObservable (this);
  }
}
```

More info here
https://mobx.js.org/migrating-from-4-or-5.html
and
https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful and the direction we might have to go in. I thought decorators were pretty cool, though.